# encodejson is not giving proper format of json

Tags: json, format

```
if ($tag == 'get_rajkot')
{
   $data=$db->get_rajkot();
   if($data!=false)
   {
        $valueresult=array();

        foreach ($data as $value)
        {
            $valueresult=$value;
            echo json_encode($valueresult);
        }
   }
  else
  {
        // failed to store
        $response["error"] = 1;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured..No get_headlines image found...";
        echo json_encode($response);
   }
}
```

db_function.php

```
public function get_rajkot()
{       
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_term_relationships join wp_posts where ID=`object_id` and term_taxonomy_id=19 ORDER BY object_id DESC LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());
    // check for result
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) 
    {
        $rows = array();
        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $rows[] = $r;
            //print_r($rows);
        }
        return $rows;
    }
    else
    {
         // profile not found
         return false;
    }
}
```

Result:

It's not giving comma between two objects and brakets `[]` at the start and at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set my sql char set after mysql_connect query  like this...
this problem was occurring due to Gujarati font

$con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_set_charset('utf8mb4',$con);